# Json format with custom Reads logic

Tags: playframework

If I have a format such as `(__ \ "category").format[String]`, how would you add validation for reads. Ex. `(__ \ "category").format[String].filter(ValidationError("Category not valid"))(ss => categories.contains(ss))`. Unfortunately, this code converts the type from Format to Reads, which means I will need to implement reads and writes separately.

Comment: In this case I would define the reads and writes explicitly and make a format that combines them: `val myFormat = Format(myRead, myWrite)` - is that what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Exactly! There doesn't look like a built in function. A downside to separating reads and writes is keys have to be defined 2 times which leads to more typing and typos.

Comment: Creating implicit helper seemed simple.     def filterReads(error: ValidationError)(f: T => Boolean): OFormat[T] = {
      OFormat(format.filter(error)(f), format)
    }